# Replace value in XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm working on a XML file that is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    <Property>
        <Name>Email</Name>
        <Value>alebbb@hotmail.com</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Resposta</Name>
        <Value>here i have ; to be replace by nothing</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>NPS</Name>
        <Value>8</Value>
    </Property>
</Properties>
```

and my map XSLT is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Properties">
       <xsl:variable name="Email" select="/Properties/Property[1]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:variable name="Resposta" select="/Properties/Property[2]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:variable name="NPS" select="/Properties/Property[3]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Email)"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Resposta)"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($NPS)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I replace ";" by nothing using replace at my XSLT map?
For example: here I have ";" to be replaced by nothing.
And expected: here I have  to be replaced by nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with the XPath-1.0 function [`fn:translate`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_translate.html).
So change your `xsl:value-of` to

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($Email,';',''))"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($Resposta,';',''))"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($NPS,';',''))"/>
```

Comment: probably better to do `normalize-space(translate(...))` so the spaces around the semicolon get coalesced as in the provided example.

Answer (score 1):

First, in XSLT 2.0 you have sequences and you can use `separator` attribute of `value-of` instruction. So, following Michael Kay comments about `translate` and changing just your `value-of` instruction to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Email, normalize-space(translate($Resposta,';','')), $NPS"
     separator=";" />
```

Output:

```
alebbb@hotmail.com;here i have to be replace by nothing;8
```

Second, if you really want to use [`fn:replace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-replace):

```
<xsl:value-of select="$Email, normalize-space(replace($Resposta,';','')), $NPS"
     separator=";" />
```

Comment: Alejandro,
what about if i need to replace the ';' and a 2 double quotes.
exemple:
     
xsl: value-of select = "normalize-space (translate ($Answer, ';', ''))"

at the $Answer i have  the text ( here i have ; to work"")
and i want to substitute the 2 double quotes too.

Result: here i have to work

Comment: @AndreSantos That's a good question. I have no time right now, but ask another  question and someone will answer.

Comment: Here's a link for solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503740/how-to-replace-select-characters-in-xslt