# How to replace select characters in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a XML file that is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    <Property>
        <Name>Email</Name>
        <Value>alebbb@hotmail.com</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Resposta</Name>
        <Value>here "i" have ; to be"" replace by nothing</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>NPS</Name>
        <Value>8</Value>
    </Property>
</Properties>
```

and my map XSLT is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="Properties">
       <xsl:variable name="Email" select="/Properties/Property[1]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:variable name="Resposta" select="/Properties/Property[2]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:variable name="NPS" select="/Properties/Property[3]/Value/text()"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Email)"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($Resposta)"/>;<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($NPS)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I replace `;` and `"` and `""` by nothing using replace at my XSLT map?
I got:

```
here "i" have ; to be"" replace by nothing
```

Expected:

```
here i have  to be replaced by nothing
```

I'm using the below for substitute the `;`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate($Resposta,';',' '))"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
<Value>here "i" have ; to be"" replace by nothing</Value>
```

the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(Value, ';&quot;', ''))"/>
```

will return:

```
here i have to be replace by nothing
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mt

Comment: Michael,
I've checked your link, but in my case, your expression is replacing all my text for nothing, it does not happen as shown in the link.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your problem using "your case": https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mt/1

Comment: Sorry bro,was my fault, it works perfectly.
Stackoverflow should put a button to pay a beer ! Thanks so much!